# Union all operations in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

i have this query :

```
(SELECT 
    month_range,
    sum(new_unmetered_feeders_rural + new_metered_defective_rural) as total,
    '' as month_range,
    '' as total_target
FROM
    tbl_metered_feeders
WHERE
    division_id = 252
        and date_format(STR_TO_DATE(month_range, '%m-%Y'),
            '%Y-%m') BETWEEN ('2018-04') AND ('2019-03')
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(month_range, '-', - 2)
order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(month_range, '-', - 1) , SUBSTRING_INDEX(month_range, '-', 1) asc) 
union all 
(SELECT 
    '' as month_range,
    '' as total_target,
    month_range,
    sum(new_unmetered_feeders_rural + new_metered_defective_rural) as total
FROM
    tbl_metered_feeders_target
WHERE
    division_id = 252
        and date_format(STR_TO_DATE(month_range, '%m-%Y'),
            '%Y-%m') BETWEEN ('2018-04') AND ('2019-03')
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(month_range, '-', - 2)
order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(month_range, '-', - 1) , SUBSTRING_INDEX(month_range, '-', 1) asc)
```

and the output of this query is as follow:

```
| month_range |      total      | month_range    | total_target|
| 06-2018     |     200         | -              |  -          |
  -           |   -             |  08-2018       |  150        |
```

expected output:

```
| month_range |      total      | month_range    | total_target|
   | 06-2018     |     200         |  08-2018    | 150         |
```

i want this to be in one row. how would i modify my query to achieve this?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Use join instead of union.

Comment: @FahadAnjum there is no common column

Comment: Is it always be one row? If yes then you can use cross join.

Comment: no it may increase

Comment: Please provide more data.

Comment: This looks like conditional aggregation (of which there are many examples in so) code using dynamic sql.